# Using RestKit to map a a naked array of URLs to Core Data Entities

Tags: core-data, restkit

I'm getting back some URLs in a naked JSON array from a web service like so:

```
[
    "https://server1.com",
    "https://server2.com"
]
```

I'd like to map these to separate Core Data Entities, but am getting an assertion failure:

```
I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:180 GET 'https://server-test.com/Client/Endpoints'
*** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *RKEntityIdentificationAttributesForEntityMappingWithRepresentation(RKEntityMapping *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong)(), /Users/jonukas/MyApp/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:83
An uncaught exception was raised
Expected a dictionary representation
```

FWIW, setting a breakpoint on `RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:83` shows that the representation that should be a `NSDictionary` is actually an `RKMappingSourceObject`.

Here is the mapping I made:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"MyURL"
                                               inManagedObjectStore:self.manager.managedObjectStore];

[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                                  toKeyPath:@"url"]];

RKResponseDescriptor *descriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                           pathPattern:@"Client/Endpoints"
                                                                               keyPath:nil
                                                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[self.manager addResponseDescriptor:descriptor];
```

My Entity has just one attribute (url) of type transformable. Here is the `NSManagedObject` subclass:

```
@interface MyURL : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id url;

@end
```

Am I doing the mapping incorrectly or is there something wrong with my entity description/object model (forgive me, I'm just starting out with Core Data)?

**UPDATE:** I tried setting an identification attribute, but it didn't seem to help:

```
[mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"url"]];
```

Turning on trace logging for `RestKit/ObjectMapping` results in:

```
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:377 Executing mapping operation for representation: (
    "https://server1.com",
    "https://server2.com"
)
 and targetObject: (null)
T restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:320 Examining keyPath '<null>' for mappable content...
D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:297 Found mappable collection at keyPath '<null>': (
    "https://server1.com",
    "https://server2.com"
)
*** Assertion failure in NSDictionary *RKEntityIdentificationAttributesForEntityMappingWithRepresentation(RKEntityMapping *__strong, NSDictionary *__strong)(), /Users/jonukas/MyApp/Pods/RestKit/Code/CoreData/RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource.m:83
…
```

I'm guessing the (null) targetObject might be my problem.

**UPDATE 2:** RestKit 0.21.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `url` attribute in your Core Data model to be `String` type. By setting it to `transformable` RestKit can't properly interpret what data type is should be so it is opting for dictionary and getting rather confused.

I assume you set it to transformable because you want an `NSURL`. RestKit can't do that for you so you should use a transient attribute to achieve that gaol.

Comment: I changed the url attribute in the data model to type _String_ (and to NSString * in the NSManagedObject subclass), but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Turn on trace logging for the mapping and check what RestKit is doing. Does it interpret the data type correctly? Also, reading the exception again, have you set any identification keys?

Comment: I tried adding an identification key earlier, but it didn't seem to make a difference. I've amend the question with what I got from the trace log and the identification attribute I used.

Comment: Ok, so it's something else entirely I think. Are you using the latest master version of RestKit? What code do you see on line 83 where the exception is raised?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 0.20.3. Line 83: NSCAssert([representation isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]], @"Expected a dictionary representation");

Comment: I can't see that code in restkit github. I suggest you upgrade to 0.21.0 and verify the code base.

Comment: I'm using RestKit via CocoaPods and 0.21.0 isn't there yet, but found the new podspec in the RestKit repo and used that. It now works! Thanks!